# TypeConverter won't convert to boolean

Tags: c#-4.0, type-conversion

I have the following test code which is giving me some problems. I want to be able to pass in a boolean as a string, EG "true" or "false" and get back a bool. The function should be able to handle other types so I can't just use Convert.ToBoolean() etc.

```
    protected static T GetDefaultValue<T>(object propertyName)
    {
        var tc = new TypeConverter();

        return (T)tc.ConvertTo(propertyName, typeof(T));
    }
```

When I call the above function with this line of code, it throws an exception:

```
bool b = GetDefaultValue<bool>("false");
```

It says "'TypeConverter' is unable to convert 'System.String' to 'System.Boolean'."

Can anyone point out how to use the TypeConverter in the way I want or does it not work this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are potentially heading for a lot of hurtin' here.  First off, not just any TypeConverter will do, you have to find the specific one that knows how to convert a string to a boolean.  You can get one with TypeDescriptor.GetConverter().  Not an issue for a bool, you'll get the System.ComponentModel.BooleanConventer.  And you must use its ConvertFrom() method, not ConvertTo.  So this works fine:

```
    protected static T GetDefaultValue<T>(object propertyName) {
        var tc = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
        return (T)tc.ConvertFrom(propertyName);
    }
    ...
        bool b = GetDefaultValue<bool>("false");    // fine
```

But beware that .NET only has a limited set of converters built-in.  Just the ones for types that you typically find back in the Properties window.  Custom types require their own converter derived from the TypeConverter class.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I thought I was going mad when the exception said it couldn't do the conversion.